# java.net.UnknownHostException: googleapis

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, grpc, apache-httpclient-4.x, grpc-java

My Spring boot app is able to make calls to Google pub sub APIs and works perfectly as expected but only when it is not behind a proxy.

I am looking to deploy my app in on-premises datacenter which requires proxy to make outbound HTTP call.

1. I used `HTTPS_PROXY` in my environment.. its not working
2. I used `grpc_proxy` in my environment.. its not working

Getting this exception

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: pubsub.googleapis.com
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:631)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
```

is there any other way to have proxy injected for google libraries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution for this. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java#grpc-clients), we would have to use `GRPC_PROXY_EXP`.

I gave it this way `GRPC_PROXY_EXP=internet.company.com:93` and it worked perfectly fine

Comment: "EXP" of GRPC_PROXY_EXP means "experimental." This is not a stable/supported feature. Use `-Dhttps.proxyHost` and `-Dhttps.proxyPort` instead.

Answer (score 0):

grpc-java and many Java HTTP libraries use the [Java-standard `-Dhttps.proxyHost=HOST`/`-Dhttps.proxyPort=PORT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) for configuring use of a proxy server.

You can't configure them with an environment variable. It is common to just pass the `-D`s on the command line. If you want to configure this globally you can change `lib/net.properties` in the JRE.

Comment: i tried this and it is still not working.. getting same exception :(

Comment: @Arun, you'd need to include the command line you used or describe what you did to determine what is wrong. The easiest problem is you put the -Ds in the wrong spot; they need to go before the -jar or class name.